# How to handle multiple versions of JDK on the same mac

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We are using java version "1.8.0_172" for our android builds. 
To run sonarqube we need java 11.

How can we direct sonarqube or android to use specific java versions as overriding JAVA_HOME is causing issues in one or the other

Comment: Try to use the wrapper.java.command setting in wrapper.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenv tool to handle multiple jdk versions on your mac.

See: https://www.jenv.be/

Using `jenv versions` you can list all jdk versions on your mac.
Then you can define a global one and a local one (specific to your current dir).

To install different versions of the jdk you could use the versions provided by AdoptOpenJDK:

See: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk

Comment: can I make my jenkins server run on one java environment, and sonarqube run on another